# Warning: Your deployed application may error out because file or folder paths not present

Tags: matlab, matlab-deployment

I get the following warning when deploying an application with matlab:

[Warning: Your deployed application may error out because file or folder paths
not present in the deployed environment may be included in your MATLAB startup
file. Use the MATLAB function "isdeployed" in your MATLAB startup file to
determine the appropriate execution environment when including file and folder
paths, and recompile your application.
]

I have tried to reduce my application to merely a program that creates a figure, nothing more, and I still get the message.

Note: When I start my application, I get the splash screen and then it crashes.

I have tried deploying with R2016b, R2017a, R2017b. How do I get around this? I have tried using my own startup file, I have used `isdeployed` as suggsted. Nothing seems to work.

All help appreciated!

Comment: What is in your `startup.m` file.  Run the exe from a dos prompt - it will write out to the dos prompt any erros which should help you see what the problem is

Comment: A fatal error has been detected by Java Runtime Environment...

Comment: It sounds like you are missing some Java Environment variables - or you are missing a library? Also, you need to put the full error message for us to determine what went wrong

Answer (score 0):

Type which startup.m -all in your command window. If you find the file then delete it from the path. Then perform the build process again. It might work.